# Matrix equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation

I have a matrix equation and I want to solve it in MATLAB. The equation is

```
X^(-1)AX=B.
```

Where `X` is an unknown symmetric `3x3` matrix, `A` is known and `B` is a diagonal matrix (There isn't any condition on `B`'s elements, just diagonal).

Please help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given it appears that you are looking for a symbolic solution which Matlab is not the best at (usually Mathematica is prefered or check out Wolfram Alpha). If you absolutely need Matlab then you could use the ['solve()'](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) command.

However, honestly you are dealing with a rather simple linear system of small dimensions so it is probably easiest to just work this out by hand. Check out [Matrix Cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) for help. Also it really just looks like you are just trying to solve for the eigenvector matrix so possibly the command eig() might help ??